# Find the Rejection Region using the Likelyhood Quotient

Tags: statistical-significance, maximum-likelihood, inference, likelihood-ratio

H0:= l=8, Ha:= l=10

from a random sample of N=9

where f(xi)=l*exp(-lxi) and a=0.05

Find the Rejection Region, please help 
I think i get confused when getting the likelyhood quotient because i get that the sum of xi must be greater than (9ln(8/10)-k)1/2 which in the end yields something not positive for calculating k in the end.